# How to convert a python list containing two numpy arrays into a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, 2d

Suppose,
X is `[array([2, 3, 4]), array([4, 5, 6])]`

I want X to be

```
array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  This is covered in any tutorial on NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
array = numpy.stack(X, axis=0)
```

You could also do:

```
array = numpy.vstack(X)
```

Comment: Your code would make it into a 1d array of `array([2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6])`, whereas the OP wants a 2d array like `array([[2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]])`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `np.array(...)` and create an array:

```
>>> X = [array([2, 3, 4]), array([4, 5, 6])]
>>> np.array(X)
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>>
```